# Basic Web Design Question

Tags: css

I have a few basic questions about web design.

1. What is the optimum size of web page in kB?
2. What resolutions are most commonly used? (best to use?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20110702232331/http://www.thechoppr.com:80/blog/2009/02/27/best-page-width-and-screen-resolution-trends/) is interesting, it shows the width (in pixels) used by some well known websites. It will help you find the ideal width (height is not important)

There is no real optimal page size, as far as I know... but you should try to reduce it of course, I like to use tools like pngcrush to do this.

Comment: Link to the article doesn't work anymore

Comment: @chux FWIW I updated the link to point to the last indexed archive from the wayback machine.

Answer (score 2):

**Optimum webpage size**

There is no optimum size, it depends on the system it is running on (think mobile vs desktop computer).

To put a KB size on it would also not only depend on the system, but the bandwidth available.  This is ever changing/improving (usually) so it's hard to put a figure on it.

Not only does it depend on these things, it also depends on what sort of content you are offering.  Is it a Javascript application?  Users will expect slower loading times.  Is it an art gallery?  People will be a bit more patient.  Is it a search engine?  People want it quick and fast most likely so will be less forgiving in the wait times.

**Optimum resolution**

Resolution again depends on platform.  Mobile platforms you are going to have to look up the resolution offered on the manufacturers website.  For desktop, a minimum of 1024x768 seems quite generous, but the gap between these minimums and super hi res monitors is ever increasing.

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends on your audience.
2. It depends on your audience.

Sorry if it's vague but the type of website you are building and the likely users you will attract will answer both of these questions. If you are building a website where the users a likely to be on 14" TFT monitors, using Windows '95 and IE5 then your answer will be different if you are building a website where your users are likely to have 23" LCD monitors, Windows 7 and FF4.10beta (because they HAVE to have the latest browser).

Comment: And don't forget about smartphones, iPads, netbooks, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would always say the actual web page file itself should be pretty small unless you have a single page with thousands and thousands of characters of text etc... the page will be inherently small, usually less than 100KB

what I try to do with images is save them at the lowest resolution that I see no loss in quality, usually I try to keep them below 500KB or at the very least below 1MB (even though most people have broadband connections, some still use dialup and some phones are not 3g so below 500KB is best and even 500KB can be bad for a dialup user.

images look alright at 96dpi  but if bandwidth is a big concern you could try going smaller.

on the other hand if its not a concern and you don't care about dialup users etc... you can use whatever you want